# Why Oracle does not include in DBA_dependencies, the objects views created with any database links?

Tags: database, oracle, dependencies, oracle12c

I'm trying to find an explanation in the Oracle documentation regarding the exclusion of views including database links. Oracle specifies that these views are absent but does not give the reason. Even if remote dependencies are not "managed" by Oracle (except rpc), existing dependencies between an object and a dblink are included in the dependencies view of the Oracle dictionary. I do not understand the reason for this exclusion.

One explanation could be the lack of management by Oracle.  "These views or procedures and their dependencies to the database link are not managed by Oracle: In such cases, the absence of dependency management is preferable to unnecessary recompilations of dependent objects." (Dependencies Among Other Remote Objects, Oracle documentation) The problem is that procedures and their database links are included in the dictionary dependencies view while views are not. This explanation is therefore not complete or accurate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "Object_VIEW" AS 
select * from Schema.target@Database_Link;
```

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROC_DBLINK AS 
 v_test varchar2(250);
BEGIN
  select x into v_test from Schema.target@Database_Link;
END PROC_DBLINK ;
```

```
select * from dba_dependencies where name = "Object_VIEW" or name = "PROC_DBLINK"
```

The result is PRC_DBLINK referend the database link. The dependencie between Object_VIEW and Database_Link are excluded.

If we perform this query we won't find our view either

```
select * from dba_dependencies where referenced_link_name = 'Database_Link' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the explanation included in Question is matching as per the documentation of Oracle.

You are not able to find the view - DB link dependencies but you are able to find the procedure - DB link dependencies <-- This is how Oracle developed this view.

> DBA_DEPENDENCIES describes all dependencies in the database between
>   procedures, packages, functions, package bodies, and triggers,
>   including dependencies on views created without any database links.

Refer: [THIS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D74F9AD4-387A-4773-8C40-337F4152645F.htm#REFRN23053)

If you want to find the dependencies between view and DB link then you must use external SQL on `USER_VIEWS`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for your response Tejash, but I would have liked to understand **why** Oracle excludes these dependencies from its dictionary (view vs dblink) since it references the dependencies between procedures and dblink

Comment: Because Oracle treats view in different way. Might be you are aware that `ALL_SOURCE` also do not contain information about `VIEW`

Comment: Yes, I know and I would like to understand why views are treated differently. I find no answer in the documentation or in the books. I guess there's a technical explanation and I'd really like to know it.